# Is there any way to set Point of Interest in Android Google Map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

In iOS there is setting `_mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = YES;` to display point of interest on google map as shown below in the picture[image]

we need to show same in android but can't get any thing. so far this :

[image]

Comment: there is nothing in the maps API that says allow way points. you can however use the Places API to play way points yourself. https://developers.google.com/places/android/

Comment: @tyczj we can do by `nearbysearch` API  but that need to be called every time which also have limits.

Comment: correct it has limits, like I said google does not have POI in their map API

Comment: @tyczj  but i have seen in some navigation based android app which shows POI. so my question is if they have done using `nearbysearch api` then how all the POI is displayed?

Comment: You can use the `Google Places API`. You can use its web service API calls to fetch nearby places, there are [list of place types supported](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) in its [nearby search request](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchRequests).

Comment: @ztan we already have that nearby feature in our app.  check my old comment